# Dependency jar containing ejb 3.1 and jsf pages

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7

I have a web app project which is now growing in to separate web submodules containing their own ejbs and jsf webpages.

The project structure is going to look like something following.

- parent-project
- common-module
- creditcard-module
- bankpayment-module
- some-more-payment-modules ...
- war-module

Each module except common module has its own ejbs and jsf pages.

If possible I need each module to be a standalone war and build a big war with the war module.

**EDIT**

Current structure of the project

```
war module -- 
           --| persistenceunit |
           --| entities |
           --| ejbs |
           --| cdi managed beans |
           --| controllers |
           --| jsf-pages |
           --| resources |
```

The different business units are just separated by packages. Now it is required to be able to version the different business units separately i.e. different mvn projects for each.

Structure to achieve:

```
Common module -- 
              --| persistenceunit |
              --| dao helpers |
              --| common ejb services |
              --| common managed beans |                  
              --| jsf-templates |
              --| common resources |
Creditcard module -- 
              --| related entities |
              --| ejb services |
              --| related managed beans |                  
              --| jsf-pages |
              --| specific resources |
```

And the same for other business modules, moreover one master war / ear module to contain all the wars.

Important: is it possible to share persistence unit ?
Will cdi work across the modules (at the end it is a single ear/war) ?

In essence the idea is to modulerise the project according to business needs and not purely technical layers.

How should I achieve this with maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to accomplish what you want using Maven Web overlays:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

They let you have Web resources propagate through projects via dependencies, similar to how source files and classpath resources propagate through jar files and into war files via dependencies.

Comment: I will take a look at that as well

Comment: Hi, overlays seem interesting, I tried but as soon as I have overlay with 2 wars included in the master war, all my backing beans are not being injected. I get "Target ureachable"  error

Comment: It works well if I have only on war overlayed in the master war.

Comment: Yeah, I have not personally tried to have more than one war as an overlay/dependency, so I can't say for sure if/how that works. The documentation makes it sound like it's possible. If the issue is that the classes from your non-master wars are not getting into your master war, you may need to try breaking those wars out into two projects each, a jar project with just the classes and a war project without the classes. The classes may then get propagated to your master war that way, via transitive dependencies.

Comment: It was an issue with common dependencies, which I managged useing dependentWarExclude config param.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an *Enterprise Archive* (.ear file) using the [Apache Maven EAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/):

> A Java EE application is delivered in an Enterprise Archive (EAR)
>   file, a standard Java Archive (JAR) file with an .ear extension. Using
>   EAR files and modules makes it possible to assemble a number of
>   different Java EE applications using some of the same components. No
>   extra coding is needed; it is only a matter of assembling (or
>   packaging) various Java EE modules into Java EE EAR files. (Source: [Java EE 5 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html#indexterm-47))

Create a new module with packaging **ear**. [Use](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html) the *maven-ear-plugin*, [configure the modules](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html) that you want to have assembled together.

Comment: What will be the other modules ? War,jar or ejb-jar ? I want to include common ejbs and common jsf pages in those.

Comment: I would say ejbs will be a jar and configured as an ejbModule. about _Common_ jsf pages I am not sure, probably a jar for another war?

Comment: Some modules will contain ejbs as well as jsf pages. What about them ?  Can an ejbModule (jar) have jsf pages inside ? If yes how ?

Comment: Usually, an ejbModule does not have jsf pages inside. Although, as these files are archives, it is of course possible that they contain all sorts of files.
Please update your question about how you currently structure and deploy your application. And what you want to achieve. A reproduceable example would make it easier to help you.